# Library to manage menus in embedded device for C/C++

Tags: c++, c, user-interface, embedded, menu

I'm looking for a library to manage menus. I'm looking for something which is based on configuration files. It doesn't have to manage keyboard input or display, just the menu logic. What I have in mind something like:

```
//menu.xml
<menu>
    <Start />
    <Stop />
    <Configuration displayname="Configure System">
        <Sound type="toggle" />
        <Speed display="Speed related settings">
           <Speedy type="toggle" default="on" />
           <Optimizations type="toggle" />
        </Speed>
    </Configuration>
    <Filesystem>
         <SaveSnapshot />
         <LoadSnapshot />
    </Filesystem>
</menu>
```

In the code we would have:

```
//menu.cpp
Menu menu("menu.xml");
menu.bind("SaveSnapshot",saveSnapshotPressed);
menu.bind("LoadSnapshot",loadSnapshotPressed);
menu.bind("Sound",soundSetTo);
...
void onKeyPressed(key_t key) {
...
    switch (key) {
    case KEY_UP:
        menu.goUp();
        break;
    case KEY_DOWN:
        menu.goDown();
        break;
    case KEY_ENTER:
        menu.action();
        break;
    }
// display.cpp
void render(...) {
    for (int i=0;i<menu.items().size();++i) {
        renderText(getMenuCoord(i),menu.items()[i].c_str());
    }
    ...
}
```

Such a library could be very useful to display menus in embedded device.

I'll be glad to hear if such library exists, or is there a better idea for this library.

Comment: +1 for usefulness and relevance. I'd love to see anyone who voted this closed to come up with a menu. I ended up using C code structure layout from 1995. There isn't an OOP solution. https://github.com/cacycleworks/chipKIT_ST7735/tree/master/Libraries/ST7735/examples/simpleMenu

Comment: Hi Elazar, did you manage with OOP solution ?

Comment: @ransh Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are things like Kaleido: http://www.digitalairways.com/kaleido-engine.htm
which are very nice, but pricey.

Emwin is simpler and cheaper but nothing like as rich in terms of functionality:
http://www.segger.com/cms/emwin.html

Comment: Both offer much much more than I need. I'll handle the display myself, I'll handle the control myself, I just want the inner menu logic.

Comment: FYI Segger's EmWin is $12,300.

Comment: @ChrisK - which still makes it significantly cheaper than something like Kaleido (which doesn't appear to still be in active development, but was many hundreds of thousands of pounds - depending on exact licensing terms and number of seats - at the time I wrote that post).

Comment: O_O   <--- that's my "wow face". Hundreds of thousands of pounds? I could retire on the sale of one license.

Comment: @ChrisK, yep. I had a quote from them in 2007 for a product I was working on, their demo was extremely impressive but for what we needed (which was only 2 developer seats!) they wanted a total of $216K USD plus a $1.34 product royalty.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at the Android SDK.  This too, may be more than you want to handle, but there may be value in replicating, or possibly using any tools google may have.

Comment: That's a good idea. Do you know which part of the Android SDK should I look into? I'll be glad for a reference for the particular component.

Comment: I think you will have download and install the whole SDK.  I'm not familiar enough with the SDK to be able to reference a particular part or tool.  I do know it uses a xml format for laying out the GUI elements.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but maybe someone else, has the same problem.

I think [CLI](http://alexis.royer.free.fr/CLI/) is the solution you need.

> CLI is a toolkit that allows you to easily implement C++ and Java Command Line Interfaces

It has XML configuration file and generates C++/Java source which you then link.
I haven't tested it, just found it when searching for something to create CLI menus easier.

Comment: Here is another CLI.. https://github.com/gbmhunter/clide-cpp